# how to use gatling feeder to use the data once per user for entire duration?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

In gatling how to achieve the following?

### sample_testdata.csv

```
orderId
101112
111213
121314
131415
```

### sample test running with 4 users and multiple iterations

```
user1 should use orderId 101112 for all the iterations
user2 should use orderId 111213 for all the iterations
 and so on ...
```

I am not able to find `uniqueonce` strategy in feeder.

code:

```
scenario("Get Art")
  .during(test_duration minutes) {     
  feed(fdr_arts)
  .exec(_.set("hToken",hToken))    
  .exec(_.set("hTimeStamp",hTimeStamp))
  .exec(_.set("gToken", gToken))
  .exec(actionBuilder = http("Get Arts")
  .post(getArtUrl)
}
```

Comment: Try `.queue`



From documentation:
`When using the default queue strategy, make sure that your dataset contains enough records. If your feeder runs out of record, behavior is undefined and Gatling will forcefully shut down.`

Comment: @Amerousful queue is the default and it is taking in sequence for each iteration. I don’t want them to get changed for each iteration.

Comment: can you post your scenario code?

Comment: I'm assuming that you've got some kind of loop construct in your scenario and you're calling .feed inside it. But that's just a guess. You'll need to post your code

Comment: @james-war I am not using the loop. below is the scenario`scenario("Get Art").during(test_duration minutes) {
    feed(fdr_arts)
      .exec(_.set("hToken",hToken))
      .exec(_.set("hTimeStamp",hTimeStamp))
      .exec(_.set("gToken", gToken))
      .exec(actionBuilder = http("Get Arts")
        .post(getArtUrl)`

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario includes .during - which is a looping construct - and inside that you're calling feed. So each user is going to keep on looping for `test_duration` and on each loop it's going to pull the next value from the feeder.

To get the behaviour you want, you need to put the feeder before the loop...

```
scenario("Get Art")
  .feed(fdr_arts)
  .during(test_duration minutes) {     
    .exec(_.set("hToken",hToken))    
    .exec(_.set("hTimeStamp",hTimeStamp))
    .exec(_.set("gToken", gToken))
    .exec(actionBuilder = http("Get Arts")
    .post(getArtUrl)
  }
```

Comment: I don't need new value assigned for every iteration (user1 should use orderId 101112 **for all the iterations**)

Comment: this is what my solution does - each user will now get a new value from the feeder then use that for all requests

Answer (score -1):

```
val txn_getArt = exec(_.set("hToken",hToken))    
    .exec(_.set("hTimeStamp",hTimeStamp))
    .exec(_.set("gToken", gToken))
    .exec(actionBuilder = http("Get Arts")
    .post(getArtUrl)

// Chaining it after feeder does the trick in scenario

scenario("Get Art").repeat(5000){feed(fdr_arts).exec(txn_getArt)}
```

Comment: On contrary to @James Warr 's solution, yours will have each vu grab a new record on each repeat iteration.